# Button with multiple nested elements not returning the right target in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button which have multiple elements inside

```
<button onClick={this.selectButton.bind(this)} id="cash">
  <img src="../resources/cash.png" alt="" className={`${styles.imageWidth}`} /><br />
  CASH
</button>
```

my function to get the element:

```
selectButton(event) {
  this.event = event;
  console.log(this.event.target.id);
}
```

When I click on the borders of the button it works as it brings the right id, but when I click on top of the image, the console logs an empty string or nothing.

What would be the right path to fix this issue?

Comment: The image is probably to big. It is maybe even big as the button? If you add `onClick={this.selectButton.bind(this)} id="cash"` on the image also, then it probably works, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.target` is a reference to the item that was clicked, so in this case, when you're clicking on the centre of the button you're actually clicking on your image element.

`event.currentTarget` is more likely what you're looking for, which references the element that triggered the event.

There are a couple of things to note about your approach though.  One of the great things about react is you rarely need to access DOM elements directly.  A 'more react' solution would be to wrap your button in a custom component, and pass your ID down through custom properties, like so:

```
class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
  }
  onClick() {
     this.props.clickHandler(this.props.id)
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.onClick}></button>;
  }
}
```

And then you can use it in your main component like so:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  selectButton(id) {
     console.log(id)
  }
  render() {
    return <MyButton clickHandler={this.selectButton} id="cash" />;
  }
}
```

Note, it's also better to bind your callbacks outside of the render(), to avoid constantly generating new functions.  In this example I've moved it to the component's constructor so it only happens once.